# Prove that the composition of Lie algebra derivations need not be a derivation.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, derivations

In case the definition is not standard, my book defines a derivation $D \in \text{End}(\mathfrak{g})$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ as a linear map such that:

$D([X,Y]) = [D(X), Y]\ +\ [X, D(Y)]$ for all $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$

It is well-known that for two derivations $D$ and $D'$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, $[D, D'] = D \circ D'\ -\ D' \circ D$ is again a derivation of $\mathfrak{g}$.

However, the exercise asks for an example of a Lie algebra and two derivations such that the composition $D \circ D'$ is not a derivation. My idea was to take the Heisenberg Lie algebra, but I have been unable to find two derivations whose composition is not again a derivation. Am I missing something simple? I feel like this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If you take the 3x3 Heisenberg matrices and take for example $D$ as the matrix which is only 1 in $D_{1,2}$ and $D'$ only 1 in $D_{2,1}$. Their composition would then be a matrix which is only 1 in {1,1} (this is just matrix multiplication), but if I write it out, this is also a derivation.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No agreed, I already found that question posed, but it's about general derivations that only need to respect the Leibniz rule for multiplication within the algebra, not the Lie bracket. Thanks for your example, though, it still looks fairly challenging for me, but I think I'll manage!